# Different memory allocations in linux and windows?

Tags: linux, gcc, memory, tree, malloc

I have a tree (T*Tree: binary tree with many elements in the node) implemented in C++.

I want to insert around 5,000,000 integer values in it (let's say from 1 till 5,000,000). The tree size should be around 8 * 5,000,000 byte or 41MB in memory (according to my implementation which is reasonable).

When I display the size of the tree(in my program by calculating the size of every node), it is 41MB as normal. However when I checked in **Windows 32bit>>"Task Manager"** I found the memory taken is **732MB!!**

I checked that there is no extra malloc in my code. Even after I freed the tree by traversing from node to node and deleting them(and the keys inside) the size in  "Task Manager" becomes 513MB only!!

After that I compiled same code in **Linux Ubuntu 32bit**(virtual machine on another PC) and ran the program. Again tree size does not change in my program i.e. 41MB as normal, but in **"System Monitor"** memory is **230MB** and when freeing the tree nodes in my program the memory in "System Monitor" remains same 230MB.

And in both Windows and Linux if I freed & reinitialized the tree and insert again 5,000,0000 integer values, the memory is increased by double like if the previous space is not freed and used somewhere (which I am not able to find where).

The question:

**1)** why are those huge memory differences in Windows and Linux although the code & input data is same?

**2)** why freeing the Tree nodes doesn't reduce the memory to some reasonable value like 10MB.

code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByKaCojxzNa9dEt6cEJNeDI4eXc

[image]

below are some snippets:

```
typedef struct Keylist {
    unsigned int k;
    struct Keylist *next_ptr;
};
typedef struct Keylist Keylist;

typedef struct TstarTreeNode {
    //Binary Node specific
    struct TstarTreeNode *left;
    struct TstarTreeNode *right;
    //Bool rightVisitedDuringInsert;

    //AVL Node specific
    int height;

    //T Node specific
    int length; //length of keys array for easy locating
    struct Keylist *keys; //later you deal with it like one dimentional array
    int max; //max key 
    int min; //min key

    //T* Node specific
    struct TstarTreeNode *successor;

};
typedef struct TstarTreeNode TstarTreeNode;

/*****************************************************************************
 *                                                                            *
 *  Define a structure for binary trees.                                      *
 *                                                                            *
 *****************************************************************************/

typedef struct TstarTree {
    int size; //number of element(not number of nodes) in a tree
    int MinCount; //Min Count of elements in a Node
    int MaxCount; //Max Count of elements in a Node
    TstarTreeNode *root;

    //Provide functions for comarison elements and destroying elements
    int (*compare)(int key1, int key2); //// -1 smaller, 0 equal, 1 bigger
    int (*inRange)(int key, int min, int max); // -1 smaller, 0 in range, 1 bigger
} ;

typedef struct TstarTree TstarTree;
```

Insert function of the tree uses dynamic allocation i.e. malloc.

**Update**

according to what "John Zwinck" pointed out (thanks John), I have two things now:

**1)** The huge memory taken in Windows was because of the compiling options in Visual Studio, which I think enabled debugging and a lot of extra things. When I compiled in Windows using Cygwin without that options i.e. "gcc main.c tstarTree.c -o main" I got same result as in Linux. The size now in Windows>>"Task Manager" becomes 230MB

**2)** If OS is **64bit** then let's see how the size is calculated (as John said and as I modified):

```
5 million unsigned int k. 20 MB.
5 million 4-byte pads (after k to align next_ptr). 20 MB.
5 million 8-byte next_ptr. 40 MB.
5 million times the overhead of malloc(). I think for 64bit OS it is 32 bytes each (according to John provided link). so 160 MB.
N TstarTreeNodes, each of which is 48 bytes in the full code.
N times the overhead of malloc() (I think, 32 bytes each).

N is the number of nodes. I have a resulting balanced complete tree of height 16 so I assume the number of nodes are 2^17-1. so the last two items become 6.2MB(i.e. 2^17 * 48) + 4.1MB(i.e. 2^17 * 32) =10MB
```

So the total is: 20+20+40+160+10= 250MB which is somehow reasonable and close to 230MB.

However I have Windows/Linux **32bit** it will be (I think):

```
5 million unsigned int k. 20 MB.
5 million 4-byte next_ptr. 20 MB.
5 million times the overhead of malloc(). I think for 32bit OS it is 16 bytes each. so 80 MB.
N TstarTreeNodes, each of which is 32 bytes in the full code.
N times the overhead of malloc() (I think, 16 bytes each).

N is the number of nodes. I have a resulting balanced complete tree of height 16 so I assume the number of nodes are 2^17-1. so the last two items become 4.1MB(i.e. 2^17 * 32) + 2MB(i.e. 2^17 * 16) =6MB
```

So the total is: 20+20+80+6= 126MB it is a little far from 230MB which I get in "Task Manager" (if you know why please tell me?)

**Currently the remaining important question is**, why isn't the tree freed from memory when I am freeing all the nodes and keys in the tree using this code:

```
void freekeys(struct Keylist ** keys){
    if ((*keys) == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    freekeys(&(*keys)->next_ptr);
    (*keys)->next_ptr = NULL;
    free((*keys));
    (*keys) = NULL;
}


void freeTree(struct TstarTreeNode ** tree){
    if ((*tree) == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    freeTree(&(*tree)->left);
    freeTree(&(*tree)->right);

    freekeys(&(*tree)->keys);
    (*tree)->keys = NULL;
    (*tree)->left = NULL;
    (*tree)->right = NULL;
    (*tree)->successor = NULL;
    free((*tree));
    (*tree) = NULL;
}
```

and in main():

```
TstarTree * tree;
...
freeTree(&tree->root);
free(tree);
```

**Note:**

The tree is working perfectly (insert, update, delete, lookup, display...) but when trying to free the tree from memory nothing changed in its size

Comment: Did you implement the binary tree or use a tree from stl or other library? If you implemented it could you show the code?

Comment: @ZabojCampula Thank you for your reply. It is my implementation pls check the new link above.

Comment: Your source code link does not work (it just shows a list of four files, but cannot open).  Please post a few snippets of how you construct nodes as text in your question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck my friend just click the the download button at the top of the page in that link. Those files are compressed in .rar extension that's why cannot be opened directly. Pls let me know if you are able to download them as I mentioned.

Comment: @JohnZwinck please re-download the .rar file again and check the picture attached above

Comment: I am not going to download your RAR files.  I don't think many others here will either.

Comment: @JohnZwinck actually the code is a little bit long (There is only one rar file containing four .c files), so what do you suggest?

Comment: Please post a few snippets of how you construct nodes as text in your question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck pls check above.

Comment: @JohnZwinck One of the things that I want to know is simple. When I am compiling and running on Windows10 32bit it is taking 700MB from RAM after inserting but in Ubuntu16 64bit it is taking 200MB from RAM. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

You say your data takes:

> 8 * 5,000,000 byte or 41MB in memory

But that is not correct.  Looking at your code there are two main structures:

```
struct Keylist {
    unsigned int k;
    Keylist *next_ptr;
};

struct TstarTreeNode {
    TstarTreeNode *left, *right;
    Keylist *keys;
    TstarTreeNode *successor;
};
```

Let's say we have 5 million integers to store, as in your example.  What will we need?

- 5 million `unsigned int k`.  20 MB.
- 5 million 4-byte pads (after `k` to align `next_ptr`).  20 MB.
- 5 million 8-byte `next_ptr`.  40 MB.
- 5 million times the overhead of `malloc()`.  [Likely 16 bytes each.](http://prog21.dadgum.com/179.html)  80 MB.
- N `TstarTreeNodes`, each of which is 48 bytes in the full code.
- N times the overhead of `malloc()` (again, 16 bytes each).

If N is 500,000 (for example, I don't know the real value but you do), those last two items add up to 32 MB.  That brings the total to at least 192 MB as a bare minimum.  **Therefore, seeing 230 MB of memory usage in Linux is not surprising.**

Some systems, especially when optimization is not fully enabled at build time, will add more bookkeeping and debugging information to each block allocated with `malloc()`.  **Are you building with optimization fully enabled?**

One way you can save a lot of overhead is to stop using `Keylist` and just store the integers in plain arrays (created with `malloc()`, but only one per `TstarTreeNode`).

Comment: Thanks a lot John. This gave me insight on how to calculate the size. Please check the update above (I want to see why the tree is not freed from memory using the code above). The tree is working perfectly (insert, update, delete, lookup, display...) but when trying to free the tree from memory nothing changed in its size.

Comment: By the way for Linux/Ubuntu I am using 32 bit (not 64bit sorry for that. I had many VMs, so I got confused which 64bit and which 32bit), but the machine is 64bit.